# Why does my async code work in the controller but not in the model?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, sequelize.js

I am using bcrypt 3.0.6.  I have the following code in my `Model` file:

```
User.prototype.validPassword = async function(password) {
  try{
    // original code:
    // return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
    console.log(match);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
};
```

and I call it from my controller:

```
try {
  if (!req.body.userName || !req.body.password) throw "Invalid Login"
  user = await User.findOne({
    where: { userName: req.body.userName }
  })
  if (!user) throw "Invalid login"
  const match = user.validPassword(req.body.password);
  // const match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (!match) throw "Invalid login";
  // build token
  ...
});
} catch(error) {
  res.status(500).json({
    "msg": "Server Error",
    "error": error,
  })
}
```

When I debug it, `match` is `undefined`.

If I do the compare in the controller, it works as expected.  I would much rather the comparison be in the model file.  What am I doing wrong here?

I am new to async/await code but I have used it successfully to implement several other controller methods in the same project.

Comment: Despite naming it `returnValue`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe The comment shows my original construct.  the return value was added so I could put a break point in and see the value returned by the bcrypt compare method.

Comment: Have you tried putting an `await` before the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while but I was finally able to figure out what I did wrong.  I was using async/await too much.  The following code works as I expected it to do:

```
User.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};
```

I missed the fact (or more directly the importance of the fact) that `bcrypt.compare` returns a promise.  I just needed to return that promise and `await` it to resolve.

And in the controller:

```
  if (!user) throw "Invalid login";
  const match = await user.validPassword(req.body.password);
  if (!match) throw "Invalid login";
  // build token ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i have used `async/await` in js and understood it, you should return a promise in your `validPassword` method. Because the method is using `await` itself is an async method which runs outside the normal flow of the controller.

So based on your code i would recommend changing it to something similar to this:

```
User.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    try{
      // original code:
      // return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
      console.log(match);
      resolve(match)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      reject();
    }
  }
};
```

and the controller:

```
try {
  if (!req.body.userName || !req.body.password) throw "Invalid Login"
  user = await User.findOne({
    where: { userName: req.body.userName }
  })
  if (!user) throw "Invalid login"
  try {
    const match = await user.validPassword(req.body.password);
    If (!match) throw "invalid login";
    // build token
  } catch (err) {
    throw "Server error";
  }

  ...
});
} catch(error) {
  res.status(500).json({
    "msg": "Server Error",
    "error": error,
  })
}
```

As an alternative you could reject the promise If match is false and evaluate the reject in the catch

Comment: I don't see how the above would indicate a failed password match.  It would only fail if it threw an error.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, i totally missunderstood the usage of bcrypt.compare and its return value. Ich adjusted the code examples.

Comment: If you see my solution below, `bcrypt.compare` already returns a promise if no callback is supplied.  I was over thinking it.  I just needed to return that promise and `await` for the result in my controller.  Thanks for the honest attempt.  It put me on the right track.